# Passive skill VS. Active skill

Tags: word-usage

In a computer game, why do they call a skill which is always on as "passive skill", whereas a skill which needs user's operations as "active skill"?

It feels like, to me, it's upside down. You call the living volcano as 'active volcano' not 'passive volcano', right?

Answer (score 3):

Active skills are active because you have to **act** to use them, for example by clicking a mouse button. Passive skills don't require any user actions, they are characteristics or traits that may modify active skills.

Similarly a volcano which is acting (by steaming, smoking or erupting) is an active volcano. A volcano that is quiet is called a "dormant volcano", and if it will never become active again, it is an "extinct volcano".

Answer (score 0):

An active skill is a skill that needs an action from the player to trigger its effect, whereas the effects of passive skills, once acquired, are permanent.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, which is correct.  But it seems to be just repeating my answer.  This is also an old question.  There are lots of new questions which need new answers